# How to make Bootstrap popover events work?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dom-events, bootstrap-popover

I have added a Bootstrap popover via data attributes and I want to hide that popover after sometimes when it has been appeared. So as mentioned in [bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/#events) I thought I could achieve that via `shown.bs.popover` event. But It doesn't seem to work.

My attempt:

```
<a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" role="button" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="focus" data-bs-content="First do as it follows" data-timeout="2000" id="submit-btn1" data-animation="true">Done</a>
<script>            

$("submit-btn1").on("shown.bs.popover", 
                function(){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $("submit-btn1").popover("hide")
                    }, 5000);
                });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: You are missing the `#` on `$("submit-btn1")`

Answer (score 0):

You where missing `#` on `$("submit-btn1")` and also you had an extra `});` on your script. I modified the code, this should work.

```
<a tabindex="0" id="submit-btn1" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" role="button" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="focus" data-bs-content="First do as it follows" data-timeout="2000"  data-animation="true">Done</a>

<script>            

$("#submit-btn1").on("shown.bs.popover", function(){     
   
   setTimeout(function(){   $(this).popover("hide")   }, 5000);

});

</script>
```

> Also, a suggestion, make sure you are not using attributes without any
> utility. This  tag of yours may have many that are not really been
> used. This is to achieve a cleaner code, which is always good,
> for easier understanding.
>
> I always position the `id` in front or after the class, is an important
> attribute to be able to see it easily.